# VB net object numbers

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to select, lets say a textbox with a number.
How can I do that?
Example: Textbox1.text = "Hello"
For the record lets say that Label1 = 1
I've tried:

```
Textbox(Label1.text).text = "Hello"
Textbox & Label1.text = "Hello"
Textbox+Label1.text+text = "Hello"
```

Comment: (First Question Review) In your sample is "Hello", not a "number"? Can you rephrase the question a bit?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the control collection by name:

```
'find control named textbox1
Me.Controls("textbox" & (1).ToString).Text = "Hello"
```

As a Method:

```
Private Sub SetTextboxText(namePart As String, text As String)
 Try
   Me.Controls("textbox" & namePart).Text = text
 Catch
 End Try
End Sub
```

USage:

```
SetTextboxText(label1.Text, "Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

its not so clear what your question about, but if you tried to assign an index of the object

```
Textbox(Label1.text).text = "Hello"
```

you should try this

```
Textbox(Convert.ToString(Label1.text).text) = "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using variables in object names is not possible. You can put your objects (TextBoxes) to a list and acces them within that list using index.

I am not sure about VB.net syntax, but basically something like:

```
list = new list of TextBoxes.
list.Add(TextBox1)
list.Add(TextBox2)

dim index as int = int.parse(Label1.Text)
list(index).Text = "Hello"
```